# Making a responsive grid layout of images by way of <ul><li></li></ul>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid of images responsive to changes in the size of the browser.

How to accomplish this using a list?

Ideally, I'd like to make it so they stay in evenly spaced rows. So, say the sizes get so that there are three rows of four on top and one of three on the bottom - best if that row of three could be centered, so that there isn't a 'missing square' in the bottom right.

The way it is set up right now works - for mobile. But I would like to make it scale larger for any desktop or tablet use.

```css
.main{
 width:22.5rem;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;

}

.interest {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.interest li {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 5.375rem;
 height: 6.5rem;
 line-height: 70%;
}

.interest img {
 width: 5.375rem;
 height: 5.375rem;
}

.interest a {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 5.375rem;
 height: 1rem;
 font-size: .75rem;

}

.interest a:hover{
 color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

<div class="interest">

<ul>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">Crime/<br>thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thingL.svg">Gun thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing/Safety</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing Rel</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/Jthing.svg">Jobs/Economy</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">Quality of thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">Reproduction</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing</a></li>
 <li><a href="#/thing"><img class="portal" src="img/thing.svg">thing Services</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly committed to doing it with lists, too. As long as there is a way to have a grid layout of clickable hrefs

Comment: Do you have anything against doing this with just inline blocks? Because they can work pretty nicely in this sort of situation. (Try resizing for different screen widths.) http://jsfiddle.net/sndp0e9q/

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it sort of sounds like this is something that flexbox was made for, no?

Comment: Flexbox ey? What's that?

Comment: Also how to resize for different screen widths would be helpful. Working on a civic hacking app :)

Comment: Do you need a framework to use flex boxes or is that just native css?

Comment: divs with classes would be the best approach i think. If tou want to simulate different screen widths use your Browser built in tools. In chrome you have dev tools that can simulate different resolutions.
You can try to write some simple grid with @media queries.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed this using flex boxes like @Raphael Disanto said.

So far, the code works for reorganizing the images on changes in the size of the window. Still have to add specific image scaling so the images not only change position relative to the screen size, but change size too.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {

  padding: 0px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 10px;
  color: white;

}

.flex-item img {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 width: 70%;

}

.flex-item p {

}

.flex-item a {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
   -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
/*  line-height: 100px;
*/}

.flex-item a:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/civilLiberties"><img src="img/CIVIL_LIBERTIES.svg"></br>Civil Liberties</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/crimeAndPunishment"><img src="img/CRIME_AND_PUNISHMENT.svg"></br>Crime/<br>Punishment</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/education"><img src="img/EDUCATION.svg"></br>Education</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/energy"><img src="img/ENERGY.svg"></br>Energy</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/environment"><img src="img/ENVIRONMENT.svg"></br>Environment</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/gunControl"><img src="img/GUN-CONTROL.svg"></br>Gun Control</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/healthSafety"><img src="img/HEALTH-SAFETY.svg"></br>Health/Safety</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/immigration"><img src="img/IMMIGRATION.svg"></br>Immigration</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/infrastructure"><img src="img/INFRASTRUCTURE.svg"></br>Infrastructure</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/internationalRelations"><img src="img/INTERNATIONAL-REL.svg"></br>International Rel</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/jobsEconomy"><img src="img/JOBS-ECONOMY.svg"></br>Jobs/Economy</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/qualityOfLife"><img src="img/QUALITY-OF-LIFE.svg"></br>Quality of Life</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/reproduction"><img src="img/REPRODUCTION.svg"></br>Reproduction</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/taxes"><img src="img/TAXES.svg"></br>Taxes</a>
</div>
<div class="flex-item">
 <a href="#/socialServices"><img src="img/Social-Services.svg"></br>Social Services</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have stuck with your `ul` you could still use flexbox with `ul` markup. Also be aware this will not work in IE9 or earlier.

Comment: I would also investigate making your images as background images for the `a` tags and look at [background image scaling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images)

Comment: I also found out it doesn't work in safari and firefox. firefox = one long row, and safari = one tall row on the left

Comment: You need to expand on `-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;` as that is vendor specific, you want `flex-flow:row wrap` and other vendor prefixed versions.

Comment: Ar yea? Can you be a little more specific?